# How to detect ambiguities in linking using ld

Tags: c, debugging, linker, fortran90

We had a problem that took us one week to solve. It was because a function "ddot" was declared in a fortran program (in static .a archive) as well as in a C program (in .so dynamic library). The linker "ld" linked to the wrong entry.

It turned out that the problem was solved when the fortran function was renamed from "ddot" to "ddot_sparse". But it took us one week to find that.

Would it be possible to do this kind of detection automatically? As a matter of fact the linker accepted for the "ddot" from fortran and the "ddot" from the C library as legitimate. Could this be reported by the linker?

Or maybe it is a bug of "ld" that such things are not detected? The man page of ld says "Normally when a symbol is defined multiple times, the linker will report a fatal error." This clearly did not happen here.

Alternatively, are there tools to show up the tree of dependency between the various symbols of a binary executable? That would be wonderfully useful. Something that shows for each symbol the used symbol and the file from which they originate.

Answer (score 1):

By default `ld` should link on a first comes first serves basis. For example

```
ld main.o -lfortran_archive -ldynamic_library
```

Will link first against any symbold that are in `libfortran_archive.a` and then the remaining symbols against `libdynamic_library.so`. If you swap the linking order

```
ld main.o -ldynamic_library -lfortran_archive
```

Then you will have the reverse effect. This will allow you to determine which library has priority symbols.

I am unaware of a universal switch that will allow you to output warnings in `ld` on multiple symbols. Especially that e.g. Linux and OS X come with different linkers. But you can use `nm` to output the list of all symbols that are defined in an object file/library

```
cat <(nm -U libfortran_archive.a) <(nm -U libdynamic_library.so) \
    | grep -o "[^ ]*$" | sort | uniq -c | grep -v "\s*1"
```

Comment: Actually, I would be happy with a solution for linux, which as far as I know uses exclusively the GNU linker ld. I do not use OS X.

I guess I will have to write some perl scripts in order to be able to detect such coincidence more systematically. I am surprised that this does not already exist and I am surprised by the behavior that you indicate. The option --allow-multiple-definition and the manual entry seems to indicate that by default ld would complain about multiply defined symbols.